# Setting height to 100vh shows vertical scroll bar in small screen devices

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

In my angular app, I want my login form to be centered on the screen. I applied necessary CSS styles and everything works fine without any vertical scroll bar on my laptop and desktop i.e medium and large screens. When I view the form on my phone, vertical scroll bar appears and form is not centered vertically as shown in the image below.

[image]

The login html form and its CSS file are

login.component.html

```
<div id="divPage">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <!-- Content of the form -->
    </div>
</div>
```

login.component.scss

```
#divPage {
    background-color: #9caae2;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column; 
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
 }
```

Above login component is part of the root app-component whose html and scss files are

app.component.html

```
<div class="app-wrapper">

<!-- Page Content -->
<div id="page-content">
    <div>
        <router-outlet>
            <!-- Login component shown here -->
        </router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.component.scss

```
.app-wrapper {
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   align-items: stretch;
}

#page-content {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0px;
   min-height: 100vh;
   transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

I don't want vertical scroll bar to appear on small screen. I tried setting vertical-align to middle in #divPage as mentioned in few answers to similar questions but it did not work for me. I don't understand what is happening. Please help me out with this.

Comment: try instead of vh %. or you can use max-height

Comment: I tried adding max-height: 100% instead of height:100vh inside #divPage CSS class and it fails to center on medium and large screens as well

Comment: Try `box-sizing: border-box;` on `divPage` and on `wrapper`. This will remove the horizontal and vertical shift caused by the padding

Comment: @bron I tried adding box-sizing as you mentioned but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are on an iPhone, as there is a bug where 100hv is bigger than the screen due to the address bar.
When the address bar is shown, the page is actually 100vh + the address bar size.

There are several solutions, here's a few of them: https://medium.com/@susiekim9/how-to-compensate-for-the-ios-viewport-unit-bug-46e78d54af0d

I'm currently using a javascript approach to solve this, something along the lines of:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    document.body.height = window.innerHeight;
}
window.onresize(); // called to initially set the height.
```

Not very nice, but it does work.

Comment: When I try to use document.body.height inside a @HostListener, it causes an error 'Property 'height' does not exist on the type 'HTMLElement'. The code is

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']) onResize() {
    document.body.height = window.innerHeight;
  }

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
.example-content {
    min-height: calc(100vh - Xrem); //X to be set accordingly.
}
```

Where you can try setting this **'X'** in dev tools until scroll disappears. According to me, this works well for all devices.

Comment: I am using an iPhone. I can only run website on it (i.e deployed code) but can't run dev tools and keep changing the X value

Comment: Okay! that's understandable. But was it helpful?

Comment: Should I set the min-height value for #divPage or wrapper?

Comment: I would prefer to try on wrapper and as i dont know the actual design.

Answer (score 0):

Changes Here `vh` to `%`

```
#page-content {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0px;
   min-height: 100%;
   transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: I made the change you mentioned but it still doesn't work